# Maintain Table Alternate Row Background after dynamically adding then hiding a new row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/bfa78/1/

I have **table** in which i have **alternate rows** with **different background colour** using CSS:

```
table tr:nth-child(2n){
    background:#f8f8f8;
}
```

My Application requires me to **dynamically add and hide new rows** to the **table** ( as shown in the Fiddle) .

```
$('#addrow').on('click',function(){

    $('#datagrid').find('tr:nth-child(2)').after(' <tr class="newrow">  <td>sa</td><td>asd</td><td>sdsa</td><td>sda</td>   </tr>');

});

$('#hiderow').on('click',function(){

    $('#datagrid').find('tr.newrow').fadeOut(400);


});
```

The **problem** is when i am **adding a new row and then hiding that row**, the alternate **background pattern breaks**. Is there a way I can fix it? I tried giving different classnames to the original rows and applying the above css on them but its not helping.

Answer (score 0):

You're setting the alternate style only to the rows that have the `original` class. But you're adding rows with a different class name (`newrow`).

Change from:

```
table tr.original:nth-child(2n){
```

to general rows selection:

```
table tr:nth-child(2n){
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bfa78/3/

Comment: I tried initially with tr:nth-child(2n) but it was not working, so i added the class original to older rows. The problem is not when i add a new row, its when i hide it ...Its hidden but it stays in the DOM...and style get awry...

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply colors with javascript

```
   function applycolors(){
var trs= $('#datagrid tr:not([style="display: none;"])') ;
    for(var i=0;i<trs.length;i++){
        if(i%2!=0){
         trs[i].style.background="#f8f8f8";
        }else{
         trs[i].style.background="#ffffff";
        }
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vikramjakkampudi/bfa78/6/